# My VBA code does not work in Office 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I developed and tested some VBA code using **Office 2013 and was working perfectly**. BUT when I ran it on **Office 2007, the code breaks** at this line...

```
ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value = "=" & Worksheets("Formula").Range("AlarmsStatusFormula").Value
```

the error msg I received was Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error. D6 is part of the same table that contains a column called "Message".

AlarmStatusFormula contains this formula

```
IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Recover"," NR"},[Message]))),"FOUND","")
```

Note the AlarmStatusFormula named range has the workbook scope.

Can it be something to do with the way Excel 2007 handles named ranges vs 2013?
Can you please help with this?

Comment: I notice that in the line that breaks, the named range is: Alarm**s**StatusFormula; while every other time you refer to it, you call it: AlarmStatusFormula.

Comment: When you deal with formulas in VBA, you should use `.Formula` rather than `.Value`.

Comment: Some formulas in Excel 2007 got different names that same formulas in more recent versions of Excel. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2551525/function-names-changed-in-non-english-versions-of-excel-2010-sp1. Maybe that SEARCH is available with a different name in Excel 2007?

Comment: @Mistella this is a typo error. the named range is AlarmsStatusFormula.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007 it should be `TableName[Message]` rather than just `[Message]`

Comment: @pnuts - the Option Explicit is commented out

Comment: @FunThomas - the code works fine in Excel 2013 but not in 2007. I will try your suggestion anyway